# Reset file associations to application defaults in newer builds of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-association

In earlier versions of Windows 10 it was possible to recreate the default associations an application would normally have. For example, with the press of a button, I was able to make MS Word authoritative for any associations that MS Word would normally set up as a default, even if they were assigned to other applications in the meantime. More importantly, this was possible even in cases when everything seemed fine with the associations.

I can't seem to find this same possibility in newer builds of Windows 10. Yes, I can set "file type and protocol associations" per app but there doesn't seem to be the possibility to reset, i.e. rewrite these associations. Is this functionality gone entirely or is it just hard to find?

Specifically, I feel the need to do this since, in case of MS Word, in the list of file type and protocol associations, everything is selected and thus seems fine, however, MS Word complains each time it opens a *.doc-file that it is not set to be the default application for the file type. Clearly, something is wrong. I guess a reinstall or repair would solve the situation, too, but a file associations reset used to be the simpler solution in such cases.

Comment: Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps and click on "Reset to the Microsoft recommended defaults"  This in in V1909 and V2004

Comment: Hi John, will this not reset all associations globally and not just for the application I have issues with?

Comment: That is all there is. I do not see associations being lost on any of my 3 Windows 10 machines here or on any client machine. You need to figure out what is causing the problem because it does not appear to be common place. Make a new, test Windows User Profile, log into the new Windows Account and see if icon association is stable in the new Windows Account

Comment: Hi John, as mentioned, in previous builds, the reset was possible per application, not only globally. Hence my question, if this possibility is now lost. I'm using this machine for all kinds of development and testing, it's not unusual that some things get messed up in the process. In this specific case, it's not a big issue, I can solve this in other, quicker ways then creating a new profile. I was just curious.

Comment: This functionality recently changed. To the best of my knowledge the functionality is gone. The change is pretty stupid. It’s like two steps forward and one step back with Microsoft. File associations have been a sore point with Win 10 since the beginning. Microsoft can’t seem to figure out that people are not going to use Microsoft edge and other BS and the constant push to force changes is getting rather old.

Comment: Microsoft admits a bug hee and "Woody" (read down the article) has a Powershell script to address this. I have not tried it:  https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/09/microsoft-confirms-file-association-bug-in-windows-10-version-1803/     V2004 looks different here, but I am not sure if this has fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion I think you and others might like. Configure your file associations in the order you would prefer and then make a backup copy of them. After Microsoft messes them up, then a simple double click (and a reboot) will restore them. This is what I have had to resort to doing, and it works for me.

Now keep in mind that when I say "make a backup copy" I am talking about exporting the settings from the Registry. There are some people who simply shouldn't be messing around with Regedit, and i'm not going to bore you with all the usual warnings that go with using it. In other words do so at your own risk, I'm not responsible if someone hoses their machine.

That being said, the most important information is exactly where to go in the registry to get the file associations.

So fire up regedit and navigate to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`

Right-click on the `FileExts` key and select "export"

Name it and Save it.

Now when Microsoft changes things on you go to this file and double-click on it to
import it, and then reboot. Good luck.

EDIT: A couple things I guess I should point out. Any time you install another program it might be wise to export a fresh copy.

If you just did a system rebuild then you want to be sure you have installed all of the previous applications before importing.

Another suggestion might be to use system restore before trying the import.

You could end up with errors if you don't. Like I said, it's not for everyone.